# Por que se recomenda colocar os códigos JavaScript no final do escopo da tag body?

Tags: javascript, html, header, body, footer

Tem alguma regra quanto a utilização de scripts na *tag* `<head>`? A W3C não deixou muito clara as regras de utilização.

Comment: Colocando abaixo permite a renderização progressiva, é consegue uma maior paralelização do download. [Neste artigo em inglês cita mais beneficios](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque assim os elementos principais da página e que devem ser os mais relevantes já podem ser renderizados antes do termino de verificação e interpretação das partes em JS que costumam ser importante só após o fim da carga da página.

Se o código JS for colocado no começo ou no meio, a renderização da página fica obstruída até que todo o *script* seja analisado.

Obviamente isto não funciona tão bem assim em todos os casos. Pode ser que a renderização correta e completa só seja possível quando o *script* começa ser executado.

Existem uma série de técnicas para controlar melhor essa carga e em poucos casos esta recomendação deve ser seguida.

Então nada impede e em geral colocar na *tag* `head` é vantajoso, principalmente se carregar assincronamente ou com retardamento:

```
<script defer>
```

ou

```
<script async>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Defer.html).

Veja [como funciona](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html).

[Onde dá para usar o `defer`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer).

[Onde dá para usar o `async`](http://caniuse.com/#search=async).

Comment: obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu postei lá na duplicada, e adicionei alguns detalhes extras.

Comment: Eu acredito que sua resposta deixou as coisas mais claras, eu já havia pesquisado a pergunta que consideraram duplicada, porém não sanou totalmente a minha dúvida. Agora que você publicou sua resposta na duplicada, acredito que vai ajudar mais pessoas.